# Microsoft Visual Studio: Create installer with Database

Tags: visual-studio

how could I create a installer in Visual Studio with database extractor??

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "database extractor" - I'm guessing you want to install your application - are you also wanting to install a) a DBMS (e.g. SQL Server Express), or b) one or more databases (e.g. an .MDF file for SQL Server), or c) both, or d) None of the above

Comment: a.) I want to install my database together with the program. So then i need to create a installer that will install the program at the same time it will extract/install the database/

Comment: What type of database are you using?